# Windows phone telegram messenger run app display error: auth.sendCode

Tags: c#, windows-phone, telegram

I have download telegram windows phone on the machine and build with visual 2013.
When running through the interface enter a phone number and send the code to the server then get the message: auth.sendCode 63835064. RPCError 400 API_ID_INVALID.

Comment: The message is quite self explanatory, don't you think so? Have a look [at the docs](https://core.telegram.org/api/errors#400-bad-request): did you set your API ID at all?

Comment: At the first time I thought the missing libraries so i do not understand this error. 
After consultation document you gave me was fixed.
Thanks best regarder.

Comment: What did you do to fix the error?

Comment: I follow the step guide :
Go to ‘API development tools’ and fill out the form.
You will get basic addresses as well as the api_id and api_hash parameters required for user authorization.
Then I copy api_id and api_hash power to class contants in project.

Comment: Ah ok, you hadn't signed up yet.